# Vim spell-checker does not recognize concatenated words (German)

Tags: vim, spell-checking

When for example typing "Beispielwort", vim's spell-checker proposes "Beispiel Wort". It accepts Beispiel-Wort, though.

There are two problems with that:

- In German, using hyphens to concatenate words is bad style. The right way is to just write them together - the second word starting with a lower case letter, of course.
- Additionally, the proposed "Beispiel Wort" is not German at all.

Is there a way to tell vim to not accept "Beispiel Wort" and instead consider "Beispielwort" as correct?

Comment: Vim being used for spell checking German rather than writing code is not a "programming tool". This is topical for Superuser.

Comment: Vim is a text editor, not a programming editor. Spell-checking is even a built-in feature. http://www.vim.org/about.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Short**: Install this https://github.com/ganwell/vim-hunspell-dicts

**Long**: This is a limitation of MySpell dictionaries that are downloaded by Vim by default. MySpell is more focused on "straightforward" languages like English. There is HunSpell which was designed for the "complex" Hungarian language.

Vim implements most of the HunSpell features, but not all. So I had to patch the German HunSpell dictionaries to work with Vim. It should recognize the same words as HunSpell does. I am not aware of any problems, suggestions are welcome on github. (Link above)

BTW: I recommend to install HunSpell dictionaries for German on your system, too.

Comment: Thank you, that indeed makes the situation much better! Still not perfect, though. Would be nice if vim fully supported this feature :(.

Comment: I think the reason I need to patch the HunSpell dict is a missing feature plus a bug in Vim. Maybe when fixing the bug the missing feature comes almost for free.

Answer (score 0):

`:help spell` says `zg` to add as a good word and `zw` to add as a bad word

Vim has its own spell-check implementation, but it uses external dictionaries. You can use the dictionaries installed on your system, by converting them to the Vim format:

vim -c "mkspell! myde /usr/share/myspell/dicts/de_DE | qa"

There are more complete dictionaries that the default ones like [this one](http://sourceforge.net/projects/germandict/files/) that can partly solve this problem. You can convert these to Vim format, too.

Comment: That's wrong. The dictionary file format for hunspell includes rules for concatenating words. As it is literally impossible to add every German combination to a dictionary (you can basically combine ANY words) using zg in every second sentence is just not a solution.

Comment: I am aware of that, I simply prefer to have a lot of false positives that I will add to my dictionary over time that taking the risk to have false negative (if you concatenate words that should not be concatenated). It's a matter of taste.

Comment: Ok, I see the point. There is one problem left, though, even if you accept the concatenation not to work automatically: Why does it propose "Beispiel Wort" which is plain wrong?

Comment: Because Beispiel and Wort are correct individually. Those dict-based spell checker do the other way around, they consider that you could forget a space between the words and try to correct it. They are not syntax checker ; ) (which would be very cool, I agree)

Comment: It's not that German has a lot of words, but rather that German orthography does not use spaces to separate words. In English we also have big phrases that are clumps of nouns like "law school entrance requirement examination". Under the "German rules", that would be written as "lawschoolentranceexamination". This is reminiscent of early Fortran: the designers thought it was a good idea to strip all whitespace from Fortran code before lexically analyzing and parsing it, oops! So then `doi=1,10` was a loop start, and `doi=1.10` was an assignment to `doi`.

Comment: @Math The false-positives are a valid point. A dictionary containing most common compound words combined with a custom list is good solution too. Since I have to live with HunSpell in LibreOffice, Mozilla-Software, Chrome and any Apple Software, I'd rather improve and spread HunSpell.